# System Partitions Over Two Drives

Tags: partitioning, unix, ssd

I have a machine with two drives a Compact Flash card (CF) and a Solid State Drive (SSD).  Recently I have been experiencing failures of both the SSD and the CF.

When I sent these back to the manufacturer for analysis, they reported that the SSDs and CDs are healthy - but that it appears that the partition table has become corrupt.

Using a Kickstart I made my Linux filesystem with the partitions split over the CF (to hold the operating system), plus the SSD (to hold my data):

```
/ on the CF
/boot on the CF
/usr  on the CF
/home on the SSD
```

Would Unix have an issue with using the CF to boot and run the operating system and using the SSD to store files?

Has anyone experienced any issues of this kind?

Comment: Which version and release of Linux or UNIX-like OS? Putting /home on a second drive is OK, BTW.

Comment: It is a Fedora 12 system.  I'm evening wondering if the act of booting up could be cuasing an issue?